# TemplateDoesNotExist at / What is wrong?

Tags: python, django

I got an error,TemplateDoesNotExist at /
app/index.html or index.html .
app(child app) is in testapp(parent app),and app has index.html・urls.py・views.py .urls.py of app is

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
views.py of app is 
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

urls.py of testapp is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from app.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
]
```

render's argument of views.py in app was changed into 'index.html',but same error happens.What is wrong?(the way to write directory?)
How should I fix this?
Traceback says

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py" in index
  5.     return render(request, 'index.html')

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  25.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the setting file

```
 TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

means that Django will look at the templates from templates/ directory under your project.

***OR***

SETTINGS_PATH may not be defined by default. In which case, you will want to define it (in settings.py):

```
import os

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And if you want to go like this

***app/index.html***

*then you must make app folder inside templates directory*

*try this*

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['/your/dir/here/templates',],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: thx ur comments.I wrote ur codes, but same error happens.What do u think other problem?

Comment: do you have TEMPLATE_LOADERS in setting.py file?

Comment: which version of django do you use ??

Comment: I use 1.11 version

Comment: I update the answer check adding a directory in your main TEMPLATE setting. and remove above settings

Answer (score 0):

HI Your template should be in **(yourapp/templates/index.html)**

check your **settings.py** has below configuration

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['your_app_name']

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

then your **view.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I wrote ur codes, but same error happens.What do u think other problem?

Comment: check in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS=['yourapp_name'] must exist or not